# SnippingTool.exe invisible for `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`

Tags: c#

Why does `File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe")` always return `false`? I can see the file in the Windows Explorer, it is not a shortcut, the command `dir` finds SnippingTool.exe, Windows' run dialog executes `C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe` just normally and every user has at least reading and executing privileges on this file, so I can't find a reason, why this file is invisible to my application. Even, if I start my application with administrative privileges it can't find `SnippingTool.exe`. I came across this strange behavior, because `Process.Start` always threw a `Win32Exception` on this file.

Can anyone else reproduce this problem? If so, can someone explain to me, why this file is invisible to my application?

(Just in case: I'm working with Windows 8.1 x64 with .NET v4.0.30319)

Comment: Are you compiling against a "32-bit" or "AnyCPU" runtime? If so, you're probably being tricked by 32-bit filesystem redirection, and `File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe")` internally get's redirected to `File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SnippingTool.exe")`

Comment: I'm compiling against AnyCPU. Compiling against x64 worked.